# How to simulate keypress [CONTROL + T] to open new tab using webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using webdriverjs now (selenium-webdriver) for test automation.
Scenario is such that I need to open a url on one tab and another url on second tab. To open a new tab I am trying to use keypress (Control + T).

Code that I am using looks something like this:

```
driver.actions().keyDown(webdriver.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0064')).keyUp(webdriver.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```

'\u0064' is Unicode for 'T'

It would be really helpful to know what I am doing wrong and how to open new tab and shift between these tabs using webdriverjs.

(***Note**: I am using webdriverjs which is a node module and not Java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JAVA AWT robot class to press keys. This class is available in the java API itself.

You can use following code for your scenario :

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T)

r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T)
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
```

Hope this code will help you ..

Comment: Using Java Robot class has a drawback that you have to keep your browser open or the action will done on the other available screen.